# For loop for renaming files with prompt for each filename

Tags: bash, shell-script, interactive

I have to convert multiple video files in a folder. I have to rename each one of them but I need the script to prompt me to write a custom name for each filename. Here is what I've got so far:

1. First I need to remove the filename spaces which my script does with that command:

   ```
   for f in *' '*; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed -e 's/ /_/g'`"; done
   ```
2. I remove the extension of the files because I don't need it for the conversion. I use this command:

   ```
   for x in *; do mv $x $(echo ${x%*.*}); done
   ```

After that I need a for loop to rename each file in the pattern:

```
for i in * ; do mv $i $customname; done
```

The problem is that I need in that phase the script to prompt me what name to add in the variable `$customname` for each  file. Something like this:

```
Rename file1 to:
.......

Rename file2 to:
.......
```

Comment: The `echo` command in `$(echo ${x%*.*})` is completely superfluous. – And if you're just looking to remove the file extension you should not be using `*.*` (which is only incidentally working because the first asterisk is matching zero characters every time), instead use `.*`. I.e. `$(echo ${x%*.*})` should be `${x%.*}`.

Comment: And if you're using `bash` (or `zsh` for that matter) then the `sed` invocation is not necessary either. Use `${f// /_}` to replace all occurances of space with underscore in `$f`.

Comment: If you quoted properly everywhere, you wouldn't have to remove spaces in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `read` to read one line from STDIN, like this.

```
for FILE in *; do
    echo "Rename '$FILE' to:"
    read NAME
    mv "$FILE" "$NAME"
done
```

This example would require you to press Ctrl-C to abort when you're done, but you could add an extra `if` case to abort e.g. if no name was entered.

**EDIT:** If you want all your destination files to have the same file extension as the original file (e.g. if the a file was called `pogo.jpg` you'd want the renamed file to keep its `.jpg` ending, and not have to type that manually) you can change the `mv` command in the above loop to:

```
mv "$FILE" "$NAME.${FILE##*.}"
```

The `${FILE##*.}` stuff in the string above means:

- `${FILE...}` display the variable `$FILE`, but…
- `##` remove longest matching string from the beginning (just one `#` matches shortest)
- `*` match zero or more of any character
- `.` match a literal period

Only if the entire expression (`*.`) matches will it be removed, thus if there is no period in the original file name, you'll get a weird result, and the new filename will be `NEWNAME.OLDNAME`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I used for my USB-PVR before I wrote a script that gets the names from the TV programme...

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in "$@"
do
    echo Playing "$f"...
    mplayer "$f"
    echo That was "$f".
    read -p "New name? " newname

    if [ "$newname" != "" ]
    then
        mv -v -i "$f" PVR-"$newname".mkv
    fi

    sleep 1
done
```

Really tedious way to rename files if I may say so ...